# CKEditor Bold Italic Only

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Can anyone give the CKEditor configuration for **just Bold & Italic, and nothing else?**

I don't want to keep removing buttons one by one, is that the only way?

```
config.removeButtons = 'Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Anchor';
```

I want to specify what I do want (Bold & Italic) instead of what I don't.

Answer (score 0):

Use the toolbar configuration option:

```
config.toolbar = [
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic' ] }
]
```